# Flutter: Handshake error(Certificate_Verify_Failed Application Verification Failure)

Tags: flutter, dart, http, ssl-certificate, sslhandshakeexception

I have a flutter app which works well for many users Android and iOS
A single user received this error while sending a post request

```
Handshake Exception Handshake error in client (OS Error: Certificate_Verify_Failed Application Verification Failure handshake.cc:393)
```

his device is iPad 6, iOS 14.8.1

I am using [http](https://pub.dev/packages/http) library

What does the "Application Verification Failure" mean?